# Can we transfer every DFA to DFAs with start state having no in edge?

Tags: regular-language, automata, dfa, deterministic, automata-theory

The start state cannot have any "in edge" (an arrow point directly to the start state) and only out edge is possible for the start state. Other states except the start state are free of limit in DFA

I have doubt between two awnsers which are :

1.It depends on the language and is not possible for every DFA

2.YES we can

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: And yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

We can, and here is a construction to do it.

Suppose you have a DFA with one or more transitions returning to the initial state. Call the initial state q0. Then for some states q and symbols s, f(q, s) = q0, where f is the transition function.

The initial state q0 has transitions of the form f(q0, s) = qs for each symbol s in the alphabet.

Create a new state q0' and adjust the transition function f as follows:

- any transitions of the form f(q, s) = q0, change to f(q, s) = q0'
- transitions of the form f(q0', s) = q' are added for all transitions of the form f(q0, s) = q'.

Basically, we can create a new state that mimics the initial state (it transitions to other states in the same way) and then make any transitions that would normally have returned to the initial state go to the mimic instead. The behavior of the DFA will remain unchanged despite never returning to the initial state.

Of course, q0' should be accepting if and only if q0 is.

Comment: what is "qs"???

Comment: My notation is a little weird in hindsight, what I meant was that there are some transitions from q0 for each symbol s to some state qs, where the qs's are not necessarily unique. They're just the states where the transitions from q0 terminate.

Comment: got it, thanks.  so not qn, {qn,qm,...}